# Focus traversal to skip non-focusable fields

Tags: java, netbeans, focus

I have many textfields on the screen (More than the code shows).

```
private Component[] focusList;
focusList = new Component[]{
        txtArcustNo,
        txtBillTo,
        txtAcctNo,
        txtName,
        txtAddress,
        txtAddress2,
        txtAddress3,
        txtAddress4,
        txtContact,
        txtContact2,
        txtEmail,
        txtWebsite,
        txtPhone,
        txtPhone1Ext,
        txtPhone2,
        txtPhone2Ext,
        txtFax1,
        txtFax1Ext,
        txtFax2,
        txtFax2Ext,
    };
    focusTraversal = new WWFocusTraversalPolicy(focusList);
    pnlBase.setFocusTraversalPolicy(focusTraversal);
```

On a condition (i.e. user marks a checkbox on screen) I want to remove txtPhone2 and txtPhone2Ext from the focus. However if I explicitly say in the onClick event to set those 2 fields to Focusable false, then when I am tabbing through the fields, my cursor just gets stuck at txtPhone1Ext and won't go to Fax1 field, skipping the fields that I set to non-focusable.

Wondering if there is something I am missing. Any hints/suggestions are appreciated. I am using NetBeans IDE if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal). It provides an example of how to create a custom focus traversal policy. Unfortunately the example is not very complete since it also has the same problem your code does because it always assumes a component will be able to have focus.

I modified the class from the example to make sure the component is focusable:

```
public static class MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy
{
    Vector<Component> order;

    public MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(Vector<Component> order)
    {
        this.order = new Vector<Component>(order.size());
        this.order.addAll(order);
    }

    public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                                       Component aComponent)
    {
//      int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
//      return order.get(idx);

        int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent);

        for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++)
        {
            idx = (idx + 1) % order.size();
            Component next = order.get(idx);

            if (canBeFocusOwner(next)) return next;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
                                        Component aComponent)
    {
/*
        int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
        if (idx < 0) {
            idx = order.size() - 1;
        }
        return order.get(idx);
*/
        int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent);

        for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++)
        {
            idx = (idx - 1);

            if (idx < 0)
            {
                idx = order.size() - 1;
            }

            Component previous = order.get(idx);

            if (canBeFocusOwner(previous)) return previous;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
//      return order.get(0);
        return getFirstComponent( focusCycleRoot );
    }

    public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
//      return order.lastElement();

        Component c = order.lastElement();

        if (canBeFocusOwner(c))
            return c;
        else
            return getComponentBefore(focusCycleRoot, c);
    }

    public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot)
    {
//      return order.get(0);

        Component c = order.get(0);

        if (canBeFocusOwner(c))
            return c;
        else
            return getComponentAfter(focusCycleRoot, c);
    }

    private boolean canBeFocusOwner(Component c)
    {
        if (c.isEnabled() && c.isDisplayable() && c.isVisible() && c.isFocusable())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```